# Comparing two regression models when one independent vrbl subsumes another?

Tags: least-squares, model-comparison

How do I interpret the change in the betas when one of the independent variables in my model absorbs another one from a previous model? Let me elaborate.

My initial model is $$y = \text{constant} + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2 + \text {additional controls} + \text {error}$$, where the independent variables belong to financial data and the dependent variable is the stock price. I want to see the effect of each of those reported numbers on the stock price. At some point, a certain financial reporting rule has been changed and now $x_2$ can only be reported under $x_1$, not separately. So, the new model becomes $$y = \text {constant} + b_3 x_3 + \text {additional controls} + \text{error}$$ where $x_3 = (x_1+x_2)$ Assume that, in my first model, $b_2$ is significant. But now since $x_2$, isn't reported separately I don't know if the investors are going to pay attention to its existence. Maybe the investors only paid attention because it had its classification. I don't know if they will value $x_3$ as they did $x_1$. Assuming nothing else changed, (or assuming I control for year and industry fixed effects), how do I interpret the change from $b_1$ to $b_3$?

Comment: Why not re-run your old data with the new model?

Comment: @mdewey You mean comparing  $y = \text{constant} + b_1 (x_1 + x_2) + \text {additional controls} + \text {error}$ to  $y = \text{constant} + b_3 x_3 + \text {additional controls} + \text {error}$ ? I have thought of it but I'm not sure if the investors react to $x_1$ and $x_2$ similarly when they have their own separate categories. After the category for $x_2$ is  gone, investors have no way of distinguishing them so they will have to react the new category as a whole. I will check the model you mentioned but I don't want to restrict myself to the same betas assumption.